# You must have Fortify Static Code Analyzer version 16.11 or later installed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, fortify, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Hi I am working on DevOps in that I am I want to Configure the Fortify Feature in my Project For that I am following the below URL For Fortify Implementation

[enter link description here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fortifyvsts.hpe-security-fortify-vsts)

After install the HPE Security Fortify VSTS extension  in my VSTS Account and then adding the Task of "Fortify Static Code Analyzer Assessment in Build Definition and follow the Document and when I am queued the Build I am getting the below error

> You must have Fortify Static Code Analyzer version 16.11 or later installed. It may also be necessary to restart the agent from a new command-window or 
>   restart the agent service so any changes to executable PATH environment are visible to the agent.

[image]

How to Resolve the Problem

Comment: Is Foritfy SCA 16.11 installed on the agent? The extension used to allow VSTS an easy way to do a scan, you still need to get the product on your own.

Answer (score 0):

the HPE product Fortify SCA is required. 
SCA (static code analyser) is the client component that must be installed and configured on the build server.

The error message indicates that you either:

A. Don't have the product installed, or
B. Have version 16.10 or    earlier installed.

To obtain the 16.11 patch for SCA you need a valid HPE customer login. If you have one do the following...

```
1. https://softwaresupport.hpe.com/
2. Select “Product Information” tab “Downloads”
3. Login
4. Select “Software Patches”
5. “Patches”
6. Search for 16.11
```

Comment: Patch is 2.9Gb, has all OS distros